# How to turn off date links in OSX?

Tags: macos, messages, ical

In Messages and other apps, the date linking is sometimes a little unnecessary:
[image]

Is there a way to turn off data detectors on Yosemite across the board?

I know you can turn off Mail data detectors with this command `defaults write com.apple.mail DisableDataDetectors YES` and then restarting the Mail.app but I'm looking for a broader elimination of them from my system.

Comment: Great question - I hope my edit is what you wanted. The data detectors in Mail is easy to kill, but I don't know if you can just kill time detectors or if you can kill things system wide (messages, etc...) so I'm hoping for an answer here that helps us both.

Comment: Thx a lot, looks good! It feels like there should be an option in Sys.Prefs somewhere, similar to what is given under Sys.Prefs → Keyboard → Text